# Problems with DateTime.ParseExact()

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with the next parse exact:

```
Time="4/1/2015 7:10:31 a m"
FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

I'm getting an exeption:

> This string is not recognized as a Valid DateTime

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: correction:   

Time="4/1/2015 7:10:31 a m"; FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

Comment: you have a space in the `a m` is that there in your real code? Also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32031018/edit) to make corrections, do not do it in the comments. Delete your last comment and put it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format and date is not macthing, you need to use `07` in hour because you mentioned `hh` and also am has space as `a m`

```
var time="4/1/2015 07:10:31 am"; 
FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

OR

```
var time="4/1/2015 7:10:31 am"; 
FechaLeida = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: you're right, I just deleted one h and works!!  thanks